# Помогите плз найти решение, css

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, кто хорошо понимает css, помогите плз сделать меню в 2 колонки, как на фото [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сейчас так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перепробовал свойства float, display inline block и массу всякого другого, но ничего не помогает( ссылка на тему http://onfilter.ru/?theme_preview=710287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` внутри раскрывающегося блока сделать `inline-block` + 50% ширины, либо `float: left` + 50% ширины;

```css
ul>li>a:hover~.sub,
.sub:hover{
  display: block;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}

.sub ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}
.sub ul+ul {
  margin-left: -5px;
}

/* Дополнительная стилизация. */
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  background: #333;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  
}
ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sub {
  background: #ccc;
  top: 100%;
}

.sub ul {
  background: transparent;
}

.sub ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">HOVER ME 1</a>
    
    <div class="sub">
      <ul>
        <li>item-sub-1</li>
        <li>item-sub-2</li>
        <li>item-sub-3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>item-sub-1</li>
        <li>item-sub-2</li>
        <li>item-sub-3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">HOVER ME 2</a>
    
    <div class="sub">
      <ul>
        <li>item-sub-1</li>
        <li>item-sub-2</li>
        <li>item-sub-3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>item-sub-1</li>
        <li>item-sub-2</li>
        <li>item-sub-3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Это как один из вариантов. Можно флексами, таблицами.